# How to create a thread with more than one argument of any type using WINAPI in C?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, cross-platform

I am working on a multi-threaded socket library (platform-independent). Currently I am developing it on Windows using WINAPI to create threads, though I need to port the library to Linux.

Comment: Pack your arguments into a struct, pass a pointer to that struct as the thread argument?

Comment: CreateThread on Win32 is equivalent to pthread_create on Linux. Both take a function pointer and a void* arg parameter to pass to the thread function. WaitForSingleObject is the Win32 equivalent of pthread_join(). It would be pretty simple to make a nice little abstraction either with C functions or as set of C++ classes. It gets trickier if you want to have abstractions for mutexes and other synchronization primitives.  But it's doable.

Comment: btw, you have heard of Boost::ASIO, right?  It's a multithreaded socket library that works on multiple platforms. I have some issues with it, but there are many that have shipped successfully with it.

Comment: If you want answers it generally helps to ask a question.

Answer (score 4):

If you program requires to be compiled on Linux and win32, I wouldn't port the code to pthreads or some Win32 thread wrapper.

I would use the std::thread

```
 std::thread th ( my_func, arg1, arg2...);
```

Comment: [Bost thread library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread.html) is also a good portable alternative, if `std::thread` is not available.